# SFDC CLI - Connected Status - Unknown

Tags: scratch-org, sfdx-plugin, dev-hub, connection

Suddently my orgs are with `connected status` unknown, like the image below, even though I can authorize my DevHub Org without any problem

[image]

I could not find any possible solution:

- Even with a new project, the error persists
- I can authorize with no major problem, towards my DevHub Org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of tries, I saw this message:

[image]

and then, after exporting `SFDX_DISABLE_DNS_CHECK` as environment variable, with value `true`.

It worked!

[image]